# Regex replace matched and remove not matched

Tags: regex

Is there a way to replace part of matched line and remove all not matched lines with only one query using Notepad++ Replace tool?

For example:
(string in quotes should be replaced with 123)
input:

```
There is line with "quoted" part
There is another line
```

expected result:

```
There is line with "123" part
```

Comment: #Grabber's solution is not working. I have tested it with the following input >> 1st line: `abc`, 2nd line: `123 "qouted" 345`, 3rd line: `678`, 4th line: `abc "quoted" def`, 5th line: `ghi`

Comment: @Ωmega You are correct, my regex doesn't handle correctly two cases: one is when the first line(s) don't contain "quoted"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My best shot:

Find

```
(^[^\r\n]*?)("quoted")([^\r\n]*?)$((\r\n)?(?![^\r\n]*?"quoted"[^\r\n]*?$).*?$)+
```

replace with

```
$1"123"$3
```

For every pattern between `""` Ωmega answer is good, this one lets you replace a specific pattern and not everything between quotes.

Explanation:

- `(^[^\r\n]*?)`: Find any character sequence without newlines (and non greedily)
- `("quoted")`: followed by "quoted"
- `([^\r\n]*?)$`: till the end of the line

  - `((\r\n)?`:we are in the new line
  - `(?![^\r\n]*?`: look ahead (negative) to avoid a non-newline character sequence
  - `"quoted"[^\r\n]*?$)`: followed by "quoted"
- `.*?$)+`: one or more times

Tested in np++ v6.1

Comment: Of course to change pattern you need to alter the line regex AND the lookahead replacing "quoted" with what you need

Comment: When a -1 is given it is symptom of courtesy explaining why

Answer (score 1):

As a pattern use

```
([^"]*?)^(.*?)".*?"(.*)([^"]*$)
```

and as a replacement use

```
$2"123"$3
```

Comment: If you need to replace just some exact quoted string, then replace `".*?"` with `"YOUR_TEXT_HERE"`

Comment: Tested, but this won't handle correctly lines with single double-quotes in a line or with a different pattern besides "YOUR_TEXT_HERE"